# Can I connect to Ubuntu One via FTP?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ftp

Is there any way i can connect to my account via FTP (gFTP)? wget would help?

I tried connecting via HTTPS and FTP (one.ubuntu.com) with my e-mail and password (launchpad's) and didn't work.

I just want to download all my files at once, not one by one.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to get all your files is to just install the Ubuntu One client as normal.

However, if you're unable to do that for some reason, you can use u1ftp as a stopgap. [Download from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/u1ftp); u1ftp is explained by James Henstridge [here](http://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2012/07/05/u1ftp/) and there are some demonstration screencasts and descriptions [here](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2012/09/11/accessing-ubuntu-one-file-storage-via-ftp-from-any-os). It works on pretty much every desktop platform (Ubuntu, Mac, Windows, Fedora, Suse, etc), and it makes Ubuntu One available over FTP to the computer you're on, so you can access U1 directly as a network drive in Nautilus or Windows Explorer or Coda or by mounting it as a drive, and it connects securely to Ubuntu One via the [U1 files API](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud) and SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu One does not provide an FTP service. If you need all the files the best way to do it is just to use the regular ubuntu one client and setup your account.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion look at [this](http://www.rsync.net/), however if you need a local backup use unison.